# systemctl enable seems to succeed, but unit not intalled as a want per [Install] WantedBy

Tags: systemd, systemctl

Pretty new to systemd, so likely (and hopefully) missing something trivial.  Thanks in advance.

I'm trying to enable a service (`bees` btrfs dedup; unit file below), but the `enable`/`[Install]` doesn't appear to have any effect?.

I run the following, full output pasted, the `enable` seems to succeed.  I don't see anything related in `journalctl`.  First, added the unit file `/etc/systemd/system/beesd@.service` (listed below)

```
# systemctl daemon-reload
# echo $?
0
# systemctl enable beesd@.service # <-- I believe I don't need an '@name' just '@' here? 
# echo $?
0
# systemctl status beesd@.service
Failed to get properties: Unit name beesd@.service is neither a valid invocation ID nor unit name.
```

also, I don't see any `basic.target.wants/` over in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/`; but notice many things are `WantedBy=basic.target` ... so this might be relevant?

Here's the unit file, which I `mv`d to `/etc/systemd/system/beesd@.service` prior to running the above

```
[Unit]
Description=Bees (%i)
Documentation=https://github.com/Zygo/bees
After=sysinit.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/beesd --no-timestamps %i
CPUAccounting=true
CPUSchedulingPolicy=batch
CPUWeight=12
IOSchedulingClass=idle
IOSchedulingPriority=7
IOWeight=10
KillMode=control-group
KillSignal=SIGTERM
MemoryAccounting=true
Nice=19
Restart=on-abnormal
StartupCPUWeight=25
StartupIOWeight=25

[Install]
WantedBy=basic.target
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe I've found the cause;

The above unit file is a template, identified by `@`; I thought I could instantiate it withOUT an instance name ... but it appears this is wrong.  If I give it a name, it is installed as expected.

Note that I missed the `%i` in the unit file; which is the instance name; so even if it did install correctly with an empty name (I thought would default) the script/unit still probably would have failed

If you're having similar problems, this was the best comprehensive `systemd` walkthrough:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-systemd-units-and-unit-files